Time scheduled Flow with APEX containing httprequest to external service that return a value
I want to create a Time scheduled Flow that contains APEX action. APEX includes HttpRequest to external service and return a value from it. Value is used to update an existing record field. How can I do this?
System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

is thrown when debugging the Flow. AFAIK there are no DML statements inside the APEX action itself, only http request. I'm not using future annotation in method since I need to get the value from the request.
Interesting part is that Screen Flow with the same setup runs perfectly fine.
Thank you for your answers!

^^^ --> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5
